# Python different behavior printing strings with and without tuple

Tags: python

So, I've got a script (python 2.7) that pulls some values from an oracle database which are then later used in inserts or updates back to the database. The script is long so I'm not going to post all here and in almost every circumstance things work as I expect, except here:

device_id and mac_id are pulled from the database by some means

executing this:

```
print "device_id is %s" % device_id
print "mac_id is %s" % mac_id
```

gives this:

```
device_id is 117281
mac_id is 3C:07:54:4A:D9:B6
```

but executing this:

```
print "device_id is %s, mac_id is %s" % (device_id, mac_id)
```

gives this:

```
device_id is (117281,), mac_id is ('3C:07:54:4A:D9:B6',)
```

Why does supplying the variables in the tuple in the second execution add the extra parantheses, commas and quotes?

Comment: thanks for the improved formatting of my question

Answer (score 2):

Because they're already tuples. Putting them alone "extracts" them from the tuple for printing.

```
print "device_id is %s, mac_id is %s" % (device_id + mac_id)
print "device_id is %s, mac_id is %s" % (device_id[0], mac_id[0])
```

Comment: Doh! OK cool, that makes sense. I didn't realize I was returning those values as tuples in the sub that queries the database. Awesome, much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to `print device_id` and you will see that it is a tuple with only one element `(117281,)`.

That means the following are the same:

- `print "device_id is %s" % device_id`
- `print "device_id is %s" % (111,)`

And these are too:

- `print "device_id is %s, mac_id is %s" % ( device_id, mac_id )` is the
  same as
- `print "device_id is %s, mac_id is %s" % ( (111,), ('222',) )`

In both cases you can see that the outer tuple parentheses are removed - the tuple is unpacked and mapped to the output string. However, in the second case, there is one more level of parentheses added by you and only that tuple is then unpacked and the original one-element tuple remains. Using this in the first case would look like this: `print "device_id is %s" % ( (111,) )`.

Edit: I was writing too long and didn't see that it is already answered, sorry :D